# How can we convert LaTeX representation to symbolic math functions in matlab?

Tags: matlab, latex, symbolic-math

How can we convert Latex representation into symbolic math.

For example,

A LaTex representation

```
y = \int x^2
```

Has an equivalent symbolic math representation as

```
syms x
y = int(x*x, x)
```

Is there a function to perform this action? I know that there exists a function [latex](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html) in matlab and I want the exact inverse of this function.

Comment: Not that I know of.  If you find a tool, let us know because that would be sweet.

Comment: @rayryeng  I tried searching but didn't find anything yet. If nothing shows up in two days I will try and write a function of my own.

Comment: After a bit of searching (for a number of languages) and contemplating, I didn't find anything and suspect such a tool doesn't exist, save [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/LaTeX.html) (though I doubt the robustness of this for _actual_ documents).  The lack of static grammar and an explicit macro-to-function rule list makes a general, robust program extremely difficult, if neigh impossible, to write given any TeX math input.  So a simple, one-shot is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab latex command converts matlab's syntax to latex's syntax. There is no function in matlab that parses LaTeX syntax into matlab's.

Your closest approximation to latex syntax inside Matlab is [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/mupad.html?refresh=true).